# PHP/SQL: My form won't send data into the database

Tags: php, sql

I am in the process of building this form that lets you type some product details that will go into the SQL database.

Right now i am having a problem with PHP logging in details into my SQL database. It doesnt seem to be able to recognize my form.

It doesn't make sense because it seems that I have not made any mistakes in my code. I know the connection to my database is working, but I can not see what is wrong in my code.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<?php

ob_start();

$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "root";
$db['db_name'] = "Stockage";

foreach($db as $key => $value){
define(strtoupper($key), $value);
}

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);



$query = "SET NAMES utf8";
mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if(!$connection){
    echo "Error";
}

?>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['create_article'])){
    $identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];
    $designation = $_POST['designation'];
    $prix = $_POST['prix'];
    $quantite = $_POST['quantite'];
    $details = $_POST['details'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO produit(id, Designation, Prix, QuantiteEnStock, Details) ";

    $query .= "VALUES('{$identifiant}', '{$designation}', '{$prix}', '{$quantite}', '$details') ";

    $result=@mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die('probléme ') ;


}

if(!isset($_POST['create_article'])){
    $var = "it's not working";
}

?>

<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Create Product</h3>
    <h3><?php echo $var ?></h3>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Designation" name="designation" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Prix" name="prix" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Quantite" name="quantite" type="tel" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Details" name="details" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button  type="submit" id="contact-submit" name="create_article" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ? All answers are appreciated

Comment: whats the result of `$var`? `it's not working`?

Comment: Try to change this line: $connection = mysqli_connect($db['db_host'], $db['db_user'], $db['db_pass'], $db['db_name']); . Currently you're using constants instead of $db array

Comment: @Beginner yes, it displays 'its not working' when the form doesnt work

Comment: well if you haven't submitted your form yet that will display by default

Comment: try echo the query the manually and run it in your dbms to check if it's correct also `produit` seems you misspelled could that be the mistake

Comment: @Beginner when I submit information and check my database nothing is there

Comment: check your table, column name and structure if it really match your corresponding query or correct

Comment: whats the result `echo $query`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the action of the form to your page.php and in the Values exclude the curly braces and just house the values in ''. For example '$prix'.

Comment: Can you perform a SELECT query in your php and return a result? Just to confirm a valid connection. The next step would be to check the user of the DB is correct.

$query = "SELECT * FROM produit;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

then grab the result into an array and print

Comment: I have checked to see if the connection is good and it works fine

Comment: OK, so if your connection is fine then it must be the INSERT statement. Are you successfully getting into this: if(isset($_POST['create_article'])){ and  receiving the post vars?


If so, can you echo your query and post it here.

Comment: This is my insert statement:

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO produit(id, Designation, Prix, QuantiteEnStock, Details) ";

    $query .= "VALUES('$identifiant', '$designation', '$prix', '$quantite', '$details') ";

Comment: Ok thanks but can you echo the query out on to the page so we get the values? and then run this into the DB

Comment: ok this is weird....I did exactly what you told me.....I echoed the query, put it into my database....it says it added a row...but yet when I browse on produit I see nothing has been updated

Comment: What way are you 'browsing' - There has to be something missing here